# Showing image url after uploading it

Tags: php, image, url

I'm working on a project, and I'm looking for a script to upload an image and after uploading show the URL of the location.

I've been working on some scripts, but none of them works. Can anyone show me how to do that?

Comment: Can you please show what you have done so far? Anything got you close?

Comment: SEE... http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp look at the part that says "Saving the Uploaded File"

Comment: Also see http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php Lots of examples, and comments to help you understand how it all works.

Answer (score 1):

this one should help you, I tried it and it works well for me:
http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/199/index.html

Comment: Dont think thats a good one, suppose that User2250218 barely knows his way around with php. So do not think its a good idea to confuse him with AJAX